# No overload for method 'TryParse' takes '1' arguments

Tags: ms-access-2007, c#-3.0

Actually im trying to insert as well as update data into datagridview at run time for that i have written one code but while executing it give me Data type No overload for method 'TryParse' takes '1' arguments
my accdb table structure is like below

```
Field Datatype
Account-- Memo
AccountNumber--Number
Date--Date/Time
Description--Memo
Post_Ref--Memo
Debit--Number
Credit--Number
Balance--Number
```

**

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
        string connectionString = null;
                    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                    con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                    string cmd1 = "insert into Ledger([AccountNumber],[Account],[Date],[Description],[Post_Ref],[Debit],[Credit],[Balance])values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmd1, con);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 int accountNumber;

                    bool accountHasValue = int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["AccountNumber"].Value.ToString(), out accountNumber);

                    if (accountHasValue)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", accountNumber);
                    }

                    string accounts = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Account"].Value.ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account", accounts);

                    DateTime datetime;
                    bool dateTimeHasValue = DateTime.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Date"].Value.ToString(), out datetime);

                    if (dateTimeHasValue)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", datetime);
                    }


                    string Description = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Description"].Value.ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description);


                    string Post_Ref = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Post_Ref"].Value.ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post_Ref", Post_Ref);


                    int debit;
                    bool debitHasValue = Int32.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Debit"].Value.ToString(), out debit);

                    if (debitHasValue)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Debit", debit);
                    }


                    int Credits;
                    bool CreditsHasValue = Int32.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Credit"].Value.ToString(), out Credits);

                    if (CreditsHasValue)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Credit", Credits);
                    }

                    int Balances;
                    bool BalancesHasValue = Int32.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Balance"].Value.ToString(), out Balances);

                    if (BalancesHasValue)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", Balances);
                    }


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    con.Close();

                    Load_data();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means the TryParse method does not have an overload that accepts one parameter. If you look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx), it takes two parameters.

For the lines of code that use TryParse, first declare a variable and use it as out parameter and pass it for seeding your database. Show me the code !!! Ok, see examples below.

```
//For accountNumber
int accountNumber;

bool accountHasValue = int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["AccountNumber"].Value, out accountNumber);

if(accountHasValue)
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", accountNumber);
}

//For Datetime  
DateTime datetime;
bool dateTimeHasValue = DateTime.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Date"].Value, out datetime);

if(dateTimeHasValue)
{
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", datetime);
}

//For Debit
int debit;
bool debitHasValue =  Int32.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Debit"].Value, debit);

if(debitHasValue )
{
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Debit", debit);
}
```

Basically all lines of code that you use the TryParse, implement them as above.

Comment: i wrote your code but its giving me No value given for one or more required parameters. error for cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); i saw by using debugger , debugger is not going inside  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue of date ,credit,debit and balance

Comment: The reason the debugger not going inside the `if` statement is because the `TryParse` could no parse the value. Or there was not value to pass. Make sure your e.g. `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["AccountNumber"].Value` returns a value from the Grid

Comment: No value given for one or more required parameters execption is coming now sir iam updating my code in the question, exception coming  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); line